# Having trouble with packing and unpacking frames in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm writing a fairly simple program in Python, but it uses Tkinter, and I'm having some trouble with `pack()` and `pack_forget()`.  I'm in Python 3.4.  Essentially, I currently have a simple program, with three buttons: Play, Instructions, and Settings.  No problems.  The Play button command just executes `pack_forget()` on the `Frame(main)` which has the three buttons.

Because of this I need three separate `play()` commands for each play button, because each calls `pack_forget()` on a different frame. Is there a way to execute `pack_forget()` on whatever frame is currently packed so I can have only one `play()` function called for all three play buttons?

(Here is what the code looks like, simplified of course):

```
def play_1():
    title.pack_forget()
    game.pack()

def play_2():
    instructions.pack_forget()
    game.pack()

def play_3():
    settings.pack_forget()
    game.pack()

from tkinter import *
main = Tk()

title = Frame(main).pack()
instructions = Frame(main)
settings = Frame(main)

play_button1 = Button(title, text="Play", command=play_1)
play_button2 = Button(instructions, text="Play", command=play_2)
play_button3 = Button(settings, text="Play", command=play_3)
```

I'm just looking for a solution that will allow me to combine `play_1()`, `play_2()`, and `play_3()` into a single function.

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: Perhaps, you could have a reference to the frame that you are currently in?

Comment: @MattDMo Sorry, on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable currentFrame and when you write for example

```
instructions.pack()
```

add

```
currentFrame = instructions
```

Then you can use this function:

```
def play():
    currentFrame.pack_forget()
    game.pack()
```